# Can I add a C# web service to a VB.NET web app?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I know I can have both C# and VB.NET code on the same web app by creating folders within app_code and mapping them in the web.config (I've done this before even though  I cannot remember the details), but is there a way to add a C# wcf web service to a VB.NET web app?

Note: it's a web application project, not a web site project.

**EDIT**:

OK, I created a new WCF library project, referenced it from the VB.NET web app, manually added a svc text file and edited as follows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="CS" Debug="true" Service="MyServiceLibrary.ServiceInterface" CodeBehind="ServiceImplementation.cs" %>
```

Seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a "WCF Service Library" project in C# to create your service. In the VB.NET project, you will need to reference the WCF library, and "manually" add a .svc file that references the service defined in the library. You'll also need to add the appropriate configuration entries.

Comment: I was thinking about this option, sounds workable. What do you mean by "manually add" the .svc file? Configuration entries, I guess we're talking usual stuff like behaviour/endpoint?

Comment: Use "Add New Item" in the VB.NET project. I expect you'll simply have to add it as a text file named Service.svc, and then create the one line of text by hand. And, yes, for the configuration.

Comment: OK - seems to work (see edit)! If I understand correctly by adding the svc file I am getting the service to be hosted by the web app right?

Comment: Yes. It will be hosted by the same web app.

Comment: Hey John - a bit of a complication here, the service is working but after I added AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required I started getting an error saying either I host in IIS or remove the attribute. I thought I was already hosting in IIS, but I now noticed that the config being referenced is in the app.config of the web service project, while the bit in the web.config is being disregarded. Any suggestion other than I should probably start another question? :)

Comment: created a new question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365981/problem-hosting-a-wcf-service-in-a-web-app